# Feige Fiat Shamir Implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, math, cryptography

I'm implementing the Fiege Fiat Shamir Identification Scheme in Java, and I'm pretty sure that it's fine math-wise. (I've checked many many times) But it never works (when check is called, it is almost always false, even when called with numbers that should work). I've gotten it to work before without sequences, (`k` value of 1), but now it doesn't work. Help!

```
public class ZKPTimeTrials {

public static int gcd(int p, int q) {
    if (q == 0) return p;
    else return gcd(q, p % q);
}

public static int randomR(int min, int max) {
    Random randgen = new Random();
    return randgen.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
}

public static int getRandomCoprime(int n) {
    int result = n;
    while (gcd(n, result) != 1) {
        result = randomR(2, n-1);
    }
    return result;
}

public static int[] makeSi(int k, int n) {
    int[] result = new int[k];
    for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        result[i] = getRandomCoprime(n);
    } 
    return result;
}


public static int[] makeVi(int[] si, int n) {
    int[] result = new int[si.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        result[i] = (si[i] * si[i]) % n;
    } 
    return result;
}

public static int[] makeEi(int k) {
    int[] result = new int[k];
    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        result[i] = randomR(0, 1);
    }
    return result;
}

public static int makeY(int r, int[] ei, int[] si, int n) {
    int result = r;
    for(int i = 0; i < si.length; i++) {
        result *= (int) Math.pow(si[i], ei[i]);
    }
    return result % n;
}

public static boolean check(int n, int x, int y, int[] ei, int[] vi) {
    int signBit = ZKPTimeTrials.randomR(0, 1);
    if(signBit == 0) {
        signBit = -1;
    }
    int shouldY = x * signBit;
    for(int i = 0; i < vi.length; i++) {
        shouldY *= (int) Math.pow(vi[i], ei[i]);
    }
    return ((y * y) % n) == shouldY % n;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int n = 71 * 7;
    int t = 50;
    int k = 10;
    int[] si = makeSi(k, n);
    int[] vi = makeVi(si, n);

    int r = randomR(2, n-1);
    int ei[] = makeEi(k);
    int s = randomR(0, 1);
    if(s == 0) {
        s = -1;
    }
    int x = (s * r * r) % n;
    int y = makeY(r, ei, si, n);
    for(int i = 0; i < si.length; i++) System.out.print(ei[i] + " ");
    System.out.println();
    for(int i = 0; i < si.length; i++) System.out.print(si[i] + " ");
    System.out.println(check(n, x, y, ei, vi));
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is an integer overflow in makeY and check: In both functions 'result' is very likely to overflow, because you build the product first and reduce modulo n afterwards. Try to reduce mod n after every multiplication to keep 'result' small.

For example in makeY, write:

```
int result = r % n;
for (int i = 0; i < si.length; i++) {
    if (ei[i] == 1)
        result = (result * si[i]) % n;
}
return result;
```

(I also removed Math.pow() to make it more readable and efficient, but this was not an error.)

The second problem is the logic of your check function: The signBit variable is not needed, but instead you should check if y*y is equal to shouldY **or** -shouldY.

```
public static boolean check(int n, int x, int y, int[] ei, int[] vi) {
    int shouldY = x % n;
    for (int i = 0; i < vi.length; i++) {
        if (ei[i] == 1)
            shouldY = (shouldY * vi[i]) % n;
    }
    return (y*y - shouldY) % n == 0 || (y*y + shouldY) % n == 0;
}
```

With these small corrections i managed to get your code running. Hope it helps...